# How to deserialise nested JSON object in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I’m having trouble deserialising a json objet in SwiftUI. I’m relatively new to both Swift and handling json.

this is the link to the json object:

`https://www.reddit.com/r/all.json`

here is my Data Model

```
import Foundation

struct first : Codable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    
    let data : second
}

struct second : Codable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    
    let children : [third]
}

struct third : Codable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    
    let data : forth
}

struct forth : Codable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    
    let title : String
    let url_overridden_by_dest : String
}
```

and here is the code I use to deserialise the json object

```
mport Foundation
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
        func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/r/all.json") else {
            return
        }
    
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
                let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode(first.self, from: data!)
        }
        .resume()
        }
}
```

the furthest I get is the following error

```
Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.
```

I apologise if I am not giving enough detail, any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I looked at the Reddit API. You may want to learn on a more basic API before tackling that one. It is pretty complex. Also, you may find these links helpful: [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) and [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io). Quicktyp will give you the decodable, though it can be a little verbose, or misinterpret some things if it doesn't get enough data. Always review the API docs to make sure that QuickType makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there are multiple issues with your codable object. First of all, make `url_overridden_by_dest`property optional because it's not coming in all `JSON` objects.

Make `id` property constant to exclude it during decoding and add enum for coding keys.

```
struct first : Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let data : Second
    
    enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }
}

struct Second : Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()

    let children : [Third]
    
    enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case children
    }
}

struct Third : Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()

    let data: Forth
    
    enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }
}

struct Forth : Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()

    let title : String
    let url_overridden_by_dest : String?
    
    enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case url_overridden_by_dest
    }
}

func fetch() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/r/all.json") else {
        return
    }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
        let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode(first.self, from: data!)
        print(posts)
    }
    .resume()
}

fetch()
```

Output

```
first(id: F866FA04-41AE-4EB8-A790-4BF564A17920, data: __lldb_expr_16.Second(id: D203B974-4BB8-4E16-9FF9-9620017C74A2, children: [__lldb_expr_16.Third(id: AE38D7D8-A32D-495E-A29F-7598006ECA4B, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 3EAF0CAA-836E-406B-95BA-9CEEEEA5D0E3, title: "How this made me smile! Why representation matters", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://i.redd.it/k9pb9042d9981.jpg"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 70FBDC78-C45D-49E2-8C21-E4A2BE230E29, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 14B7DAC1-EC60-4DEA-9A2F-02FB7F5DA0BA, title: "Well, in his defense, he\'s a fucking idiot", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://i.redd.it/gg1gyyofi9981.png"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 3B1AD0EB-1F01-42C8-8B7C-2C05A7CA47EA, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 82146995-E8E4-49A1-B284-A0E757FF2A7B, title: "NASA workers making the selfie with James Webb telescope before launch.", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://i.redd.it/o5jq1ajig8981.jpg"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 0B326E6E-DADF-4DE4-A11E-4F131270513F, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 727C3AF3-151E-4125-A1C8-E5789AEE4636, title: "He wasn\'t ready.", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://gfycat.com/tinycircularbellsnake"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 7750D83D-22D2-4A72-8CA8-9F277245EF7B, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 113E0D14-43A9-451C-BF27-C9FC54D6F0CB, title: "Opening a $15,000 bottle of Petrus, 1961 with heated tools. This method is used to make sure that the cork stays intact.", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://v.redd.it/7pnwlpigf8981"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 5CB01E5F-C0C2-49CE-97C7-984A8D577617, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 458B66B3-72E6-4137-9D42-27AA2C55FB3F, title: "*checks notes* ", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://v.redd.it/gxui4vvwb8981"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 8956CC12-0DE9-4127-B76F-03073713042D, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: A7AA87FE-E6F8-4381-95A2-2ABD7D02D37B, title: "(chuckles) we\'re in danger", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://i.redd.it/8ofq8u6ol8981.jpg"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: BA3DE24B-1B06-4CE9-BA8B-0BE08643C21E, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 30E9B17F-606F-4C04-B885-534EDFF88FEB, title: "What a brave boy!", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://v.redd.it/oh12raxxj8981"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 78AD282A-255C-47C3-B28B-4F40182FC48D, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: A5190DBA-A835-4D7B-A8AB-47718B84F64C, title: "Immigration test", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://v.redd.it/9u5xl65z78981"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 5576F732-F19A-40BB-9BA4-B94F1D59DAD8, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 139D0F69-6418-4E24-BE44-DEFF94FE0558, title: "Mum can I have a burger", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://i.redd.it/e1q0m8d7p8981.png"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 3527478A-89BF-4234-9EB7-E1E74D922911, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 55E56319-377E-464C-ACCF-B07B56E6D96D, title: "Throwback to when Lewis took down pro wrestler Mistico prior to the 2015 Mexican GP", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://gfycat.com/illlightheartedaustralianfreshwatercrocodile"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: C42139C0-89CD-44E7-BB4A-9A6654EA949C, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 3016CAC3-5ADB-4A08-953E-3A020ACEF830, title: "Pop-up memes by PaperPaul.", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://gfycat.com/harmlessshowyflamingo"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 36B5F793-E23A-4F91-84CD-D3642CB28331, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 57DD4A1B-8152-452F-AE40-858AEA0F763B, title: "keep your forked tongue behind your teeth", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://i.redd.it/ya1enmw7v8981.jpg"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: F3A39671-52B8-4361-9ED7-BD9F964A159E, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: A95FA99F-C4A3-450F-B9D2-5149A6747F2F, title: "Police officer intentionally damages car with door while performing a search.", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://v.redd.it/88ctqnhjo7981"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 3F55982A-D0F0-4B2A-8C5C-EC1496CA392E, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 78A3320C-6C51-4907-BC66-50C27C41A9A7, title: "What is a survival myth that is completely wrong and could get you killed?", url_overridden_by_dest: nil)), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: BA261231-A1D8-43B8-9291-D0202C332D5D, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 890631DA-4D85-4211-9DDB-EFD0334B1DA7, title: "me_irl", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://v.redd.it/0licbkbwk8981"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: FFF2D8A9-F0AD-4CF3-9EAF-6148FDC4C5D9, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 7BE3702A-175D-40AB-BD2E-F936297C64AB, title: "Karens in a nutshell", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://i.imgur.com/RPGSua6.jpg"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: ECAAD4E4-F317-4B49-83D5-BE14783F1DD4, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 7F52F87F-DA69-4F5A-BD9F-A2C5663B293E, title: "Not just one more", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://i.redd.it/ijk4ajjdn7981.jpg"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: CCD2001B-2DC6-47C3-8BE1-FA10662E8AC5, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: CDF2FA47-A1CB-4B1E-86B2-C2E0D2EF6945, title: "RAP CONTEST!! Hololive X Nijisanji X VOMS", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://v.redd.it/28igaujaj8981"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 69300EDA-0907-45B5-997F-56C291528D81, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 6E8A032E-7885-4B6B-BD6D-2078C6D54408, title: "A wholesome family", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://i.redd.it/xazlesb3c7981.jpg"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 5695449D-8115-486B-849F-52D1A5144254, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 8E8B75BC-10A1-411E-BA55-868A183A1BC9, title: "Just had to close my store because no one would answer there phones.", url_overridden_by_dest: nil)), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: DD411247-0FB0-4B78-990B-6BA6987765C5, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 05C88A4B-6327-436A-B105-27AE77234BB1, title: "Being there is what keeps us going.", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://v.redd.it/3w3sst0oa7981"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 0816D46F-3539-447D-91A9-598EDBF9A27C, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 423C528E-DFEC-4532-A9E7-1F9716DFB429, title: "This glitched clock.", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://v.redd.it/9um3g5g4e7981"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 99865D58-501B-4E2F-A4E4-4003350C057A, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: 8B64FFB6-0AFE-4966-981A-D4A70C0D53D9, title: "Animal rescuer helps free squirrel from birdcage.", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://v.redd.it/o3oullaxn8981"))), __lldb_expr_16.Third(id: 360DDC86-832D-4E9F-9C4A-7EDB02C42045, data: __lldb_expr_16.Forth(id: DEED7C81-4235-4FD4-A7FD-F3EF8238C033, title: "meirl", url_overridden_by_dest: Optional("https://i.redd.it/im64hvtfp7981.jpg")))]))
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I wanted to use the 'posts' constant as a published variable in an instance of a class, How would I go about doing that? Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask

Comment: @hugh19se You can mark the `posts` property as a @Published in the class using `ObservableObject` protocol conformance and observe the value change using `@StateObject`. I would suggest you go through this article : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject